# how to reshape input image array from 1d to 3d

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I have built the image classifier as bellow:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.applications.mobilenet import preprocess_input

image_width, image_height = 224, 224
input_shape = (image_width, image_height, 3)
self.model = tf.keras.Sequential()
        pretrained_layer = tf.keras.applications.mobilenet.MobileNet(
            weights="imagenet", include_top=False, input_shape=self.input_shape
        )
self.model.add(pretrained_layer)
self.model.add(tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D())
self.model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation="relu"))
self.model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
self.model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"))
self.model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))
self.model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(len(DATA_LABELS), activation="sigmoid"))

self.model.compile(
            optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.0005),
            loss="binary_crossentropy",
            metrics=["accuracy"],
        )
```

I also had a predict function that expect input as numpy array

```
def predict(self, image):
    """Predict the labels for a single screenshot
       image -- The numpy array of the image to classify
    """
    img = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
    img = preprocess_input(img)

    prediction = self.model.predict(img, batch_size=1)
```

Now I get an image which is 1d numpy array (23280,), when I feed this to the prediction model I get error as below:

```
prediction = model.predict(np.asarray(bytearray(ss_read)))  # np.asarray(bytearray(ss_read)) is 1d numpy array (23280,)
```

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected mobilenet_1.00_224_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 23280)
```

so, how can I reshape this numpy array and make it ready for the predictor? I think I can do something like `np.reshape(np.asarray(bytearray(ss_read)), (image_width, image_height, 3))`, but the total amount of data is not exactly the same after reshape in this case (224 * 224 * 3 = 150528 > 23280). should I do something like this instead `np.reshape(np.asarray(bytearray(ss_read)), (image_width, -1, 3))`?

Comment: is (23280,) an img? That's too small to use mobile net

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your image is 3D you get that `width * height = 23280/3 = 7760`

Therefore you only have some width-height pair possibilities, namely:

```
[(95, 82), (190, 41), (205, 38), (410, 19), (779, 10), (1558, 5), (3895, 2)]
[(82, 95), (41, 190), (38, 205), (19, 410), (10, 779), (5, 1558), (2, 3895)]
```

none of which is `224 x 224`.